# git - unpacking objects (getting source files on remote)?

Tags: git, git-push, git-remote

I ran these commands:

on remote:

```
cd ~/my/projects/project1
mkdir .git
git --bare init
```

on local in git repo:

```
git remote add origin user@host:/home/user/my/projects/project1/.git
git push origin master
```

Then it pushed that repo, but I actually don't see any files I was working at, only `.git` folder. So I guess all those files were packed?

So on remote I tried this:

```
cd ~/my/projects/project1
git unpack-objects --strict < .git/objects/pack/pack-d9017753a07899310a31f891c081ed63dd93e6f0.pack
Unpacking objects: 100% (638/638), done.
```

But I don't see anything. So how can I simply get same content that I have on my local repo?

Same I mean to have in `~/my/projects/project1`:
all folders and files of source code and `.git` folder inside remote repo.

In local repo, it looks like this:
`ls -a`

```
.   base_location_extension  crm_dc_extend           .git
..  calendar_service         crm_location_extension  hr_dc_extend
```

In remote, it looks like this `ls -a`:

```
.  ..  .git
```

Answer (score 0):

You initiate a bare repo which does not have a working tree, you are misunderstanding the concept of [packing](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Packfiles) in git. Git packs objects ( files, trees aka directory snapshots, commits, ets. ) so they take less space on your disk.

Comment: How can I push without using bare init? I tried pushing on empty remote folder, but it gave me error that it is not git repository

Comment: @Andrius When you push to a remote it will just alter the references ( branches and tags ) in order to update the working tree aka HEAD you will still need to checkout a branch. So I recommend you simply clone a working tree from the bare repo.

Comment: I understand that, but I don't need to save space on my remote. That remote is for testing code remotely, so I figured I could configure remote to push everything and be able to instantly test my code there. So is there a way to just simply push everything from local to remote or unpack it somehow? I used to do `scp -r`, but I thought git might be better choice. Just now I don't see it might be for this purpose.

Comment: @Andrius I guess you can setup some hook on the bare repository to update the work tree where you cloned it. http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks